# how to count not deleted instances in array of instances?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, delete-operator

I have an array of instances in my code, like this :

```c++
class Squad : public ISquad
{
    public:
        Squad(void);
        Squad(Squad const & src);
        virtual ~Squad(void);

        int             getCount(void) const;
        int             push(ISpaceMarine*);
        ISpaceMarine*   getUnit(int) const;

        ISpaceMarine**              getUnits(void) const;
        int                         getCapacity(void) const;

        Squad &     operator=(Squad const & rhs);    

    private:
        ISpaceMarine    **_units; // HERE IS THE ARRAY OF INSTANCES
        int const       _squadCapacity;

};
```

Initialized like this in the constructor

```c++
Squad::Squad(void) : _units(new ISpaceMarine*[64]), _squadCapacity(64)
{
    return;
}
```

First, is the the good way to do ?

If yes, I try to count the number of valid instances in the array (not `NULL`, not `deleted`) but I don't know how to check if `_units[20]` is deleted for example.

How can I do it ?

He is my current way to do:

```c++
int                         Squad::getCount(void) const
{
    int     count = 0;
    while (this->_units[count] != NULL && count < this->_squadCapacity)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using STL containers? `std::list` seems appropriate.

Comment: You cannot check if the target of a pointer is deleted. Just set it to `NULL` directly after deleting. Or remove it from the list. or use smart pointers.

Comment: You cannot check if a pointer is valid. Don't use raw pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ISpaceMarine    **_units; // HERE IS THE ARRAY OF INSTANCES
    int const       _squadCapacity;
```

*- First, is the the good way to do ?*

No, this is not a good way to go and neatly shows why the std containers and smart pointers is a big improvement.

With smart pointers you express and deal with ownership automatically.

I get the impression the `Squad` manages the `SpaceMarines`, in that case you should use `std::unique_ptr`.  Your `Squad` will then look something like

```
class Squad : public ISquad
{
  public:
    size_t             getCount() const;
    void             push(ISpaceMarine&&);
    using SpaceMarineIterator = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SpaceMarine>>::iterator;
    // A typedef/using for this iterator would be appropriate.
    SpaceMarineIterator getUnit(int) const;
    // And this
    SpaceMarineIterator begin() const;
    SpaceMarineIterator end() const;

    size_t                         getCapacity() const;
    // no need for copy assign either.
    //Squad &     operator=(Squad const & rhs);    

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ISpaceMarine>> units;
  // No need for capacity. 
};
```

Now, if you need a different model for ownership you can look into `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`. Your model should make an effort to work with `std::unique_ptr` though.

Note:  Don't discard the possibility of using

```
std::vector<SpaceMarine> units;
```

Comment: Isn't `getUnits` useless without another function that returns the past-the-end iterator?

Comment: @Quentin Well spotted.